# How to spy on another module in node with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I have this js module (simplified example):

```
var dbLoader = require('dbLoader');
function MyModule() {
  this.build(){
     return dbLoader.load('yipee');
  }
}
module.exports = MyModule;
```

How on earth do I spyOn(dbLoader,'load')  ??

Because when I try I get the error

spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for load()

Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should export them both:

```
module.exports.MyModule = MyModule;
module.exports.dbLoader = dbLoader;
```

The you can import them as follows:

```
var MyModule = require('my-module').MyModule;
var dbLoader = require('my-module').dbLoader;
```